# How to start with a clean global environment when starting a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

Is it a good practice to clean an environment when starting a Shiny app? My app requires users to load a new dataset. I anticipate some potential problems if there are other data/values in the environment when users start the app.

Where and how can I clean the environment?

Thanks,
Ketty

Comment: If you have a `shiny server` restarts generally work by either doing `touch restart.txt` where your app is located or simply timing out the sessions after they are idle for some time. This way the connections will be `fresh`

Comment: Can you elaborate further? What does restart.txt contain? Is it something I should create? On a related note, if my users run the app multiple times using different dataset (in one single session), will touch restart.txt also clean the environment every time they load a different dataset? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have a look at the docs(http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/) particularly obout `Schedulers & Application Restarts`. this is an empty file and `touch` command simply modify the timestamp of the file, then shiny knows when the file was created and based on that it will restart the app. That being said, the effects will only take place for new sessions. Old session needs to be refreshed. to do this you can time users out after `n` seconds with `JS`